# SANE scanning, scanbd buttons and service permissions

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, scanning, sane

I've been trying to make this work all day. I'm almost there but something is still missing. Here's the story so far:

- Debian Jessie 8.3 headless home server
- Canon MP140 MFP scanner/printer fully supported by SANE, via USB
- SANE dll.conf configured and working (everything commented out except *net* and *pixma*)

---

`scanimage -p --resolution 300 --format=tiff --mode Gray -x 210 -y 297 > test300.tiff`
...scans an A4 paper in grayscale and saves it as tiff just fine.

---

```
sudo service scanbd status
● scanbd.service - Scanner button polling Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scanbd.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-02-19 19:24:03 CET; 23min ago
 Main PID: 1740 (scanbd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/scanbd.service
           └─1740 /usr/sbin/scanbd -f

Feb 19 19:24:03 server scanbd[1740]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
```

It appears to be running but it does not react to the buttons at all.

---

I tried stopping the service and starting scanbd as root - **AND IT WORKS!**

```
sudo scanbd -f
scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
scanbd: trigger action for button-1 for device pixma:04A9172B_ABCDEF with script example.script
```

---

So, my guess was it's some kind of a permissions problem. I tried to change */etc/scanbd.conf* and replace

```
user = scand  
group = scanner
```

with

```
user = root  
group = root
```

but then when I restart the scanbd service this is what I get, and the buttons don't work again:

```
● scanbd.service - Scanner button polling Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scanbd.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-02-19 20:07:11 CET; 4s ago
 Main PID: 2562 (scanbd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/scanbd.service
           └─2562 /usr/sbin/scanbd -f

Feb 19 20:07:11 server scanbd[2562]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
Feb 19 20:07:11 server scanbd[2562]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: Not Primary Owner (-1)
Feb 19 20:07:11 server scanbd[2562]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: Name Error (Connection ":1.96" is not allowed to own the service "de.kmux.scanbd.server" due to security policies in the configuration file)
```

I'm probably overlooking some obvious detail, but I can't really figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://sane.10972.n7.nabble.com/scanbd-problem-with-dbus-permission-td17255.html

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, I've seen it. Looks similar but from what I can see it's another issue altogether. Different environment also - Debian 6, and an older sane / scanbd combo. And some missing files that are present in my case.

Answer (score 3):

### I've finally got it all working...

The end goal for me was to get the scan buttons working. By the time I figured it out, I got the scan buttons working AND network scanning also.

**Turns out I was looking at it the wrong way, and consequently going at it the wrong way.**
I'm sorry I can't write down the exact sequence of commands to make this work as I've made quite a mess by the time I was done. But I hope I can at least help with the general logic of it.

So, either `scanbd` (the scanner button service) or `saned` (the scanner network server service) can access the scanner, but not both at same time. `scanbd` locks the scanner by constantly refreshing the button state, and `saned` locks it for use as a network scanner.

The way it works is by using ONLY `scanbd` as a service.
`scanbd` then gets to monitor the state of the buttons constantly, and fire some action if a button is pressed. But it also gets to listen on the **sane-port 6566 (tcp)**. If it detects traffic, it stops monitoring the buttons and starts up the `saned` service that then takes over. When `saned` is done being a  network scanner server, `scanbd` resumes to wait for a button press, or more network traffic on the sane-port.

In order for this to work, `saned` must be configured twice.
Both as server and client on the same machine. The server part gets started when `scanbd` detects network traffic and is described in the paragraph above.

The client part gets started either manually when you initiate a scan via `scanimage`, or when `scanbd` detects a button press. The `saned` client should be configured to connect to a network `saned` server (the same machine, so localhost, 127.0.0.1 or host name, backend '*net*') - NOT USB - thus avoiding conflicts with `scanbd`. `scanbd` then detects some network traffic on port 6566 and fires up `saned` as server, just as if it was really some network client.

The client config is in `/etc/sane.d` while the server config is in `/etc/scanbd/sane.d`. The server config must be copied there from `/etc/sane.d` (just copy the entire folder) and then modified to act as a server and communicate to the scanner via usb i.e. whatever backend the scanner actually uses. In `/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf` the SANE_CONFIG_DIR should point to the `saned` server part: `/etc/scanbd/sane.d`

Edit: Also, if the machine is firewalled, open port 6566 and load kernel module nf_conntrack_sane:

```
sudo ufw allow 6566/tcp

sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_sane
```

and if it then works, add `nf_conntrack_sane` to `/etc/modules`